# Proving a metric space is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> Let $X=C[-1,1]$ be the space of real-valued continuous maps on $[-1,1]$, and define \begin{equation}d(f,g)=\int_{-1}^1|f(t)-g(t)|\ dt\end{equation} for all $f,g\in X$. Prove that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by \begin{equation}f_n(t)=\begin{cases}
>   0,\ \text{when }-1\le t\le 0\\      
>   nt,\  \text{when } 0\le t\le\frac{1}{n}\\
>   1,\  \text{when }\frac{1}{n}\le t\le 1
> \end{cases}\end{equation}Prove that $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, and that $(X,d)$ is an incomplete metric space.

Attempt: In order to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy, we need to prove that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $m,n\ge N$ we have $d(f_m,f_n)<\varepsilon$. Note that $d(f_m,f_n)<\varepsilon$ is equivalent to \begin{equation}\int_{-1}^1|f_m(t)-f_n(t)|\ dt<\varepsilon\end{equation} To prove that there is some $N$ such that for any $m,n\ge N$ we have this inequality, do we need to consider separately cases depending on how large $t$ is? I am very unsure about how to prove this.

For the final part, proving that $X$ is incomplete, we need to show that $f_n$ does not converge in $(X,d)$. To do so, is it sufficient to note that the limit as $n\to\infty$ of $f_n$ is $1$, whereas the pointwise limit doesn't exist? If so, how do we prove this?

Comment: Hint: $|f_n(t) - f_m(t)|$ can only possibly be nonzero on $[0, 1/\min\{n,m\}]$.

Comment: Also, the pointwise limit is not 1 everywhere (look at $t \leq 0$), but it does exist. For incompleteness you have to show that there is no continuous function $f$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_n, f) = 0$.

Comment: @NickF I don't really understand... could you elaborate please?

Comment: To prove Cauchiness, you can either compute the integrals you wrote down directly (which is possible, just not fun), or you can find an upper bound on them. My first remark was that the integrand is only nonzero on an interval which shrinks to $\{0\}$ when $n, m$ are large. As for my second comment, incompleteness requires that $(f_n)$ does not converge in $X$ with respect to the metric $d$.

Comment: (Cauchiness, what an ugly word! ;-) ) If you know the space $Y:=L^1([-1,1])\supset X,$ this exercise becomes much easier: $(f_n)$ is Cauchy for $d$ because it converges in $Y$ (to some $f$), and $X$ is not complete for $d$ because it is not closed in $Y$ (it does not contain $f$).

Comment: Like any $\epsilon,N$ problem, your main work is to compute the vaue of the integral $\int_{-1}^1|f_m(t)-f_n(t)|\ dt$, then set that value $<\epsilon$, and then use that inequality to find an appropriate value of $N$.

Comment: See Example 4.17 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/metricspaces.pdf, which uses $[0,1]$ rather than $[-1,1]$, but the concepts are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first show $(f_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to $d$. You already wrote the integral form of $d(f_n, f_m)$. The integrand is (if $n \leq m$)
$$
|f_n(t) - f_m(t)| = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } -1\leq t \leq 0\\
(m-n)t & \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{m}\\
1 - nt & \text{if } \frac1m \leq t \leq \frac1n\\
0 & \text{if } \frac1n \leq t \leq 1
\end{cases}.
$$
As I remarked in my comment, you could just compute the integral directly using the Fundamental Theorem. But to be quicker, we could just define $g_{n,m} : [-1,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ by
$$
g_{n,m}(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{\min\{n,m\}}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
and then remark that $|f_n(t) - f_m(t)| \leq g_{n,m}(t)$ for all $t \in [-1,1]$. Hence the integrals are bounded:
$$
d(f_n,f_m) = \int_{-1}^1 |f_n(t) - f_m(t)| dt \leq \int_{-1}^1 g_{n,m}(t) dt = \int_0^{1/\min\{n,m\}} 1 dt = \frac{1}{\min\{n,m\}}.
$$
Clearly this goes to zero as $n,m \to \infty$, hence $(f_n)$ is Cauchy.

As for completeness, one can prove (in this particular case) that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_n,f) = 0$ for some function $f : [-1,1] \to \Bbb{R}$, then necessarily $f$ is the pointwise limit of $f_n$ (or is equal to that limit "almost everywhere". This is an example of the [Dominated Convergence Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement) However, you do NOT need measure theory to prove my claim--try proving it yourself, assuming for contradiction that $f$ is continuous). The limit is
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } -1\leq t \leq 0\\
1 & \text{if } 0 < t \leq 1\end{cases}.
$$
But, $f$ is not continuous! So even though $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_n,f) = 0$, $f$ is not in $X$, and therefore $(f_n)$ does not converge in $(X,d)$.